# Sql Syntax Error, on CREATE PROCEDURE

Tags: mysql

Work with mysql on phpMyAdmin

**SQL** :

```
drop PROCEDURE if EXISTS mi;

CREATE PROCEDURE mi()  //<-- line 3
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO User ( `name` , `password` ) VALUES ('value1', 'value2');
  SET out_param = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END

CALL mi();
```

the 'drop' is for multi testing

we have table `User` there are `id primary key` , `name varchar`, `password varchar`

**Error** :

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

thanks for any help !

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server, you need to remove the sql tag.

Comment: thank you for letting me know, the tag removed

Comment: add "delimiter $$"before create statement and "$$" after end statement,

Answer (score 1):

By default, mysql itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause mysql to pass the entire stored program definition to the server. To redefine the mysql delimiter, use the delimiter command.

You can read about this in more detail [create procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html).

Add "delimiter //"before create statement and "//" after end statement in order to execute your procedure. You can use any other delimiter as well.

Comment: Is it helpful to you ?

Answer (score 0):

In phpMyAdmin, you can set the delimiter on the SQL page, near the bottom, there is a line on the same area of the page as the Go button.  Change the separator to anything ($$ is a common one) and then add this to the end of your script.